# Parsing ethernet frames

Tags: parsing, frame, ethernet

I have ethernet frames and I want to get the TCP payload on a particular port from these frames.

How should I go about this? Are there any libraries available for parsing frames and tcp?

Platform is Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to remove the ethernet header as a first step.
Next, remove the IP header and finally remove the TCP header.
However, there can be an encryption at MAC or IP layer. In this case you need to decrypt the data before you can remove the header and extract the payload.
In any case, this is a very broad question; you should familiarize yourself with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model
I'm sure there libraries ready in Linux that do what you ask for (provided there is no encryption or you can decrypt)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try looking into libpcap/winpcap/jpcap for libs or get some ideas.

Or assuming frames are in the most simplest form (no encryption, no 802.1Q, no ... etc), they would look like this:

dmac(6)+smac(6)+etype(2)+IP_hdr(20)+TCP_src_port(2)+TCP_dst_port(2)

You can match your tcp dst port accordingly at a frame offset.